# The number prodigy : reverse sum of pattern

Tags: algorithm, math

Number prodigy is given  X - there's a X digit number N, reverse of N is M. Number prodigy is interested in finding out how many X digit numbers are of form : N+M=10^X-1 and N is expected not have trailing zeroes. Means that N%10 != 0 .

In case of X=1, 9 such combinations exist.

Comment: Ok, so? This hints at a question, but doesn't actually ask one. Furthermore, if it did, it would probably be a math question, not a programming question?

Comment: Now have to find a mathematical formula that would let you calculate how many such combinations of N and M exist which would be of X digits, reverse of each other, and their sum would be of form 10^X-1.

Any hints?

Comment: As @neminem suggested, post it in the mathematics community since it's not a programming question.

Comment: In the case of `X=1`, I think no such combinations exist.  Unless `M=reverse(N)` means something different than I think it does.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Answer (score 2):

Denote `A[i]` - the i'th digit of `A`.

We first need to understand that to get `N+M=10^X-1`, we need `N[i]+M[i]=9` for all `i`. Since `M[i]=N[X-i]`, it means we need `N[i] + N[X-i] = 9`. This means, once `N[i]` is set, also `N[X-i]`.

We can now derive a recursive formula:

```
F(X) = 10*F(X-2)
```

The idea is - we look at the first digit of `X`, we have 10 possibilities for it, and for each possibility, we set `N[0]` and `N[X-1]`.

However, this allows leading and trailing zeros, which we don't want. The first and last number can be anything by 0.

```
G(X) = 8*F(X-2)
```

The above is chosing one of 1,2,...,8 as `N[0]`, then setting (one option) the last number so `N[X-1] = 9 - N[0]`, and invoke the recursive call without restrictions. Note neither `N[0]` nor `N[X-1]` can be zero.

Base clauses:

```
F(0) = 1 
F(1) = 0
```

`F(1)=0` because there is no natural number `n` such that `n+n=9`.

All in all, we found a recursive formula to compute the total number of elements. This recursive formula can be transformed into a close one with some basic algebra. I leave this part for you.